# MongoDB with node.js - how to return data async

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've tried a few approaches to this - what I have is all my modules in one file that interact with mongodb, and in another, the express route functions that call into those async functions looking for data. The problem is that the data is available in the async function, but is not returned to the calling function, and I'm not sure how to pass it back properly (not sure if it's an issue of not waiting for the async function to return and returning the array early, or if I'm actually returning it wrong).

Here is the code for the calling function

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    db.getItemsFromCollection("Plants").then( (itemArr) => {
        console.log(itemArr);
    })
    
});
```

And the db function (two attempts, one commented out)

```
  getItemsFromCollection: async function(collectionName) {
        let itemArr = [];
        const collection = client.db().collection(collectionName);
        /*collection.find().forEach(function( doc) {
                itemArr.push(doc);
                //console.log(doc);
            })
        return itemArr;*/
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, item) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(item);
            itemArr.push(item);
        })
        return itemArr;
        
        
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) then it already supports Promise syntax:

> However, all async API calls support an optional callback as the final
> argument, if a callback is provided a Promise will not be returned.

Then you can make `getItemsFromCollection` become:

```js
  getItemsFromCollection: async function (collectionName) {
    // let itemArr = [];
    const collection = client.db().collection(collectionName);
    const items = await collection.find({}).toArray(); // don't pass callback param

    console.log(items);

    // I guess you want to get back an array of the collection item
    return items;
  },
```